# Passing argument to the function inside the object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, javascript-objects

I'm quite sure this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything related to my case.

Here's my function

```
function change(prop) {
    document
      .querySelector("img")
      .style.setProperty(`--${prop}`, `${this.value}px`);
  }

  spacing.onchange = change;
  blur.onchange = change;
```

I'm struggling with passing argument to `change` function, because if I do `spacing.onchange = change("prop")` the function will be executed immediately. I want to avoid using `addEventListener`. So here's the question, how can I pass an argument to my function?

Comment: Don't you mean passing argument **to**, not from?

Comment: You need to have a higher order function in your code so that solves your problem

Comment: @GirkovArpa thank you. Yeah mistyped that bit

Comment: @SaymoinSam where exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that by using high order function feature

```
function change(prop) {
  return function() {
    document
      .querySelector("img")
      .style.setProperty(`--${prop}`, `${this.value}px`);
  }
}

// for example
spacing.onchange = change(/*Your prop*/);
blur.onchange = change(/*Your prop*/);
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped. I think it is the most convinient way of doing that

Comment: Yes it's the common way JavaScript developers do in this case

Answer (score 1):

```js
spacing.onchange = change.bind(spacing, 'prop');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variable equal to the function definition.

```
spacing.onchange = function change(prop) {
    document
      .querySelector("img")
      .style.setProperty(`--${prop}`, `${this.value}px`);
  }

spacing.onchange(arg);
```

Comment: Thank you, but imagine having 100 object like spacing. Adding function manually to every one of them is tough

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onChanges (variables,props) {
variables.forEach((variable, index) => {
variable.onChange=function(event){
    return change(props[index]);
}
});
}

onChanges([spacing,blur],[prop1,prop2]);
```